# jQuery autocomplete with JSON not using "value" or "label"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

Sorry if there is a decent example of this somewhere outer, I've been looking for days and can't find a solution.

Gathering data from JSON file "database.json":

```
"[{\"id\":\"1\",\"state\":\"Alaska\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"state\":\"Alabama\"},{\"id\":\"3\",\"state\":\"California\"}]"
```

Here is my most recent attempt that failed:

```
$("#state").autocomplete({
                       source: function( request, response ) {
                       $.ajax({
                           url: "database.json",
                           dataType: "json",
                           data: {term: request.term},
                           success: function(data) {
                                     console.log(data)
                                       response($.map(data, function(item) {
                                       return {
                                           label: item.state,
                                           id: item.id,
                                       };
                                   }));
                               }
                           });
                       },
                       minLength: 2,
                       select: function(event, ui) {
                           $('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);
                       }
                   });
```

And of course the html:

```
<input type="text" id="state"/>
```

I have no idea where to go from here, I just want a simple drop down autocomplete. Let me know if more information is needed and I can provide.

Thank you!

Comment: any error in your console?

Comment: if the ajax request returns the value, it looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dqggjdj8/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny No error in console. I just simply don't see the values dropped down. Does that mean there is an issue with the accessibility of "database.json"?

Comment: in the success handler log the value of data like `console.log(data)`

Comment: I'm really sorry, I know little to nothing about javascript. I usually write in PHP. Could you explain what I should do? I understand the concept of console.log() I just don't know where "data" is coming from

Comment: `data` is the param to the success callback... so you need to add the console logging inside the success callback just before `response($.map(data, function(item) {`

Comment: Thanks . I get the error "data is not defined"

Comment: <datalist> is a lot easier and works most places now.

Comment: Where did you add the log

Comment: @dandavis the json I'm using now is more of a template, the actual file is too large for a data list.

Comment: i've done 8000 full names in a datalist, and it works well, how big is the list?

Comment: About 8500 coincidentally but each JSON object has about 20 attributes so I don't know how that would work into a datalist.

Comment: @user2480176 in the success callback you should be able to log the returned values... so what is the value that is getting logged in the browser console now

Comment: Ok sorry. I get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '89' in' then the JSON in my question.

Answer (score 1):

With a lot of help from @ArunPJohny I was able to get the out complete to work with the addition of

```
data  = JSON.parse(data);
```

just below `success: function(data) {`

The problem was that my JSON was saved as a string and not strict JSON so I needed to parse it first.